# Android:NullPointerException onProgressUpdate

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, dialog

okay im trying to create a progressDialog however when i run my code it comes up with a NullPointerException. Now with some help from good old logcat i can confirm that my dialog is null however i cant figure out why this is. Heres my code

```
   public class asyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
          dialog = new ProgressDialog(PetrolPriceActivity.this);
          dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
          dialog.setMax(100);
          dialog.show();
           }

         @Override
           protected String doInBackground(String...parmans){
                {

                    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){

                        Log.v(TAG, "index=" + "loop");
                        publishProgress(5);
                        Log.v(TAG, "index=" + dialog);
                    }

                    String urlString = petrolPriceURL;
                    String result = "";
                    InputStream anInStream = null;
                    int response = -1;
                    URL url = null;

                    try {
                        url = new URL(urlString);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        return null;
                    }
                    URLConnection conn = null;
                    try {
                        conn = url.openConnection();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        return null;
                    }

                    // Check that the connection can be opened
                    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
                        try {
                            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            return null;
                        }
                    try
                    {
                        // Open connection
                        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        httpConn.connect();
                        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
                        // Check that connection is OK
                        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                        {
                            // Connection is OK so open a reader 
                            anInStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
                            InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(anInStream);
                            BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);

                            // Read in the data from the RSS stream
                            String line = new String();
                            while (( (line = bin.readLine())) != null)
                            {
                                result = result + "\n" + line;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ex)
                    {
                            try {
                                throw new IOException("Error connecting");
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }

            return result;
                }
           }
           @Override

           protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress){

               dialog.incrementProgressBy(progress[0]);
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               // Get the data from the RSS stream as a string

               dialog.dismiss();

               response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.error);
               response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

               try
                {
                    // Get the data from the RSS stream as a string
                    result =  doInBackground(petrolPriceURL);

                    response.setText(result);
                    Log.v(TAG, "index=" + result);
                }
                catch(Exception ae)
                {
                    // Handle error
                    response.setText("Error");
                    // Add error info to log for diagnostics
                    errorText.setText(ae.toString());
                } 


           }
```

When publishProgress(5); occurs my logcat informs me that the variable dialog is still null afterwards so i realise my error must relate to either onPreExecute and the initializing of the dialog or some problem with my increment in onPostUpdate yet this seems less likely. Here is also my logcat which states my problem and shows my dialog is null.

```
  08-13 15:35:01.976: V/AreaURL(1676): index=http://www.petrolprices.com/feeds/averages.xml?search_type=&search_value=
08-13 15:35:03.136: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.136: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.136: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.146: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.146: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.146: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.146: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.146: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.146: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.146: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.146: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=loop
08-13 15:35:03.156: V/PetrolPrice(1676): index=null
08-13 15:35:03.286: D/AndroidRuntime(1676): Shutting down VM
08-13 15:35:03.286: W/dalvikvm(1676): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a82ba8)
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676): Process: org.me.myandroidstuff, PID: 1676
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at org.me.myandroidstuff.PetrolPriceActivity$asyncTask.onProgressUpdate(PetrolPriceActivity.java:140)
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at org.me.myandroidstuff.PetrolPriceActivity$asyncTask.onProgressUpdate(PetrolPriceActivity.java:1)
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:648)
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-13 15:35:03.326: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: And what's happend if you instantiate your dialog outside onPreExecute(). Like that : ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(PetrolPriceActivity.this);

Comment: wow.... yep that was it. Why exactly does this happen? Also maybe put this as an answer so i can say your comment was correct?

Comment: It seems you are using the dialog varaible outside of the AsyncTask or what?

Comment: Thanks the answer was to instantiate the dialog outside of onPreExecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what's happend if you instantiate your dialog outside onPreExecute(). Like that :

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(PetrolPriceActivity.this);
```

I don't know why it's happen. May be you did not enter into onPreExecute x) Add Log to see That :)

Comment: Great thanks this was the problem. Glad its fixed is all

Comment: Happy to help :) 
Don't forget +1 :p

Comment: id love too but i haven't the reputation to do this. Hopefully another user will up vote this as it is the correct answer